# OpenGL- triangle is not being displayed?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning opengl from superbible 6th edition and i can't seem to draw the triangle from the following code given in the book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "externalErrorFix.h"
#include "sb6.h"


GLuint compile_shaders(void)
{
    GLuint vertex_shader;
    GLuint fragment_shader;
    GLuint program;

    //GLSL shader sources 
    static const GLchar *vertex_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 430 core                                                  \n"
        "                                                                   \n"
        "void main(void)                                                    \n"
        "{                                                                  \n"
        "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
        "                                   vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),   \n"
        "                                   vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));    \n"
        "                                                                   \n"
        "   gl_postion = vertices[gl_VertexID];                             \n"
        "}                                                                  \n"
    };
    static const GLchar *fragment_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 430 core                              \n"
        "                                               \n"
        "out vec4 color;                                \n"
        "void main(void)                                \n"
        "{                                              \n"
        "   color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);           \n"
        "}                                              \n"
    };

    //create and compile vertex shaders
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    //create and compile fragment shader
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    //create a program attach shaders and link it 
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

    return program;
}


class my_application : public sb6::application
{

private:
    GLuint render_program;
    GLuint vertex_array_object;

public:

    void startup()
    {
        render_program = compile_shaders();
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
    }
    void shutdown()
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glDeleteProgram(render_program);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    }
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        const GLfloat color[] = { 0.0f,0.2f,0.0f,1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

        glUseProgram(render_program);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        //glPointSize(10.0f);
    }

    /*
    // First program 
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        const GLfloat color[] = { 
                                    (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
                                    (float)cos(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
                                    0.0f,1.0f 
                                };

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
    }*/
};
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

Comment: The first thing you should learn is how to error check OpenGL code. What Ghislain is pointing out to you is what the compilation log would be able to tell you much more quickly and complete. Only when OpenGL is not reporting errors, you should go and ask others for help.
[Here's](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation) information about getting the shader compilation log.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple of typos:

- `gl_postion` instead of `gl_Position`
- `out vec4 color` has a missing semi-colon `out vec4 color;`
- `glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);` appears twice in the shutdown function

Furthermore, the `init()` function is missing in the class my_application. It should in particular call `sb6::application::init()`.

If it still doesn't help, it seems that the book maintains a repository with all its samples [here](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/src/singletri/singletri.cpp). Maybe they will have corrected everything there.

Comment: No, doesn't change a thing.

Comment: There is another typo in the second shader (missing semi-colon)

Comment: fixed both of those but still does not help.

Comment: Fixed that also(but i don't know why the book had two).

Comment: The init() function is also missing. I guess that without it, nothing will happen.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you print out the error log from opengl (via glGetProgramInfoLog), debugging shaders without this makes it hard to find problems

Comment: @Ghislian actually the sb6.h header takes care of all that and windows stuff

Comment: @PsragAnvesh it does define sb6::application::init(), but it may still need to be called explicitly in the subclass. See for example [this sample](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/src/singlepoint/singlepoint.cpp). I found this repository that contains the book's samples, maybe it will be more up to date than the book? I hope it helps you further.

Comment: Actually opengl is being initialized and the window pops up fine and glClearBufferfv is filling the window with the given color but the problem is that the triangle is not being rendered.

Comment: This sounds good then. I think it's worth giving a try with the github repository that I found in the meantime, maybe there are further issues that got corrected there, and you will have the latest version. Having started with the book's version and its typos is a very good way to learn though.

Comment: @psraganvesh If the updated code in the question is what you're actually trying, then `gl_Position` still has 2 typos.